# How to install php

Tags: windows, php5

I have Apache working. I've made the required changes in the configuration file. I have made the required changes in the php.config file but still am unable to run PHP.

When i run http://localhost/test.php, it displays `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Can somebody walk me through it so I know what I'm doing wrong. Have been trying to make it work for hours and am real stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you install it on IBM360 system?

Comment: i have windows operating system and intel chipset..if thats what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

You may just want use XAMPP instead since the installation is very simple and automatically takes care of Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: +1 for xampp. It's nice and easy.

Comment: i installed WampServer but it unable to open apache server and i cannot make edits in the config file from its menu..gives me error "could not execute menu item"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on windows, go for [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php)

Is migration playing with the comments?
Answer to your menu item error

http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,40722

Comment: i did its also not working

Answer (score 0):

Your answer in the comments:

> i have windows operating system and intel chipset..if thats what you are asking

lets one fear the worst ...

- Apache for Windows comes as **32bit** or **64bit** or **ASF binary** (VCC++6) or **Apachefriends binary** (VC++9)
- PHP 5.3 comes precompiled for windows also in [a lot of flavors](http://windows.php.net/download/).

Which one of each did you actually install and where?

Nevertheless, **I think it would be instructive** even for a newbie to try to install these packages as separate components (as you tried). If nothing works, you'd use a precompiled package (WAMPP,XAMPP)

BTW: Best thing to do now might be a complete deinstallation of everyting Apache-Server and everything PHP. Then, start from scratch [**according to this**](http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/apache) description.

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

Well a walkthrough

- Download Apache 2.2 windows binary from the [download page](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22)
  (currently http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.16-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi)
  Install it. Set server name to `localhost` when asked.
- Download PHP VC6 x86 Thread Safe ZIP from [download page](http://windows.php.net/download/)
  (currently http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.3-Win32-VC6-x86.zip)
  Extract zip contents to C:\PHP
- copy C:\PHP\php5ts.dll into C:\WINDOWS
- Edit httpd.conf (C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\conf\httpd.conf), by adding these 2 lines aat the bottom

`LoadModule php5_module c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

- Restart Apache (using Apache Monitor utility from the system tray)
- done.

To test your installation, go to `C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\` directory and create a file `test.php` with this line in it:
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
And finally browse to address http://127.0.0.1/test.php